# How to get the directories' names only by using the ls command?

Tags: bash, ls

```
xxxx:~/209_repo> ls -d */
drwx------ 4 xxxx student 4.0K Jan 16 12:44 a1/
drwx------ 2 xxxx student 4.0K Jan 11 14:06 t01/
drwx------ 2 xxxx student 4.0K Jan 17 06:50 t02/
```

This one works properly. But when I go to the subdirectory of 209_repo, it comes up with a path rather than a directory name.

```
xxxx:~/209_repo/t02> ls -d /student/xxxx/209_repo/*/
drwx------ 4 xxxx student 4.0K Jan 16 12:44 /student/xxxx/209_repo/a1/
drwx------ 2 xxxx student 4.0K Jan 11 14:06 /student/xxxx/209_repo/t01/
drwx------ 2 xxxx student 4.0K Jan 17 06:50 /student/xxxx/209_repo/t02/
```

Is there any way that I can get `a1`,`t01`,`t01` only so that I don't have to extract them later on?

Comment: `ls -d /my/path/*/ | rev | cut -f1 -d/ | rev`

Comment: Doesn't work. Nothing shows up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of a `ls` option to do this.

You could try

```
(cd /student/xxxx/209_repo && ls -d */)
```

This starts a new subshell, due to `(...)` and in this subshell changes to the directory `.../209_repo` and then executes the `ls`.

After the command you are still in the directory you were before, as the change dir was only executed in the subshell.

Answer (score 3):

Or standard command to find the subtree of directories is also `find . -type d` and you can tune it and add some filtering.

Comment: Yes, `find` is more appropriate to use than `ls` here.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @user7369280, but without subshell

`cd /student/xxxx/209_repo/ && ls -d */ && cd -`

EDIT

To mitigate failing ls command, and return to wd:

`cd /student/xxxx/209_repo/ && ls -d */ && cd - || cd -`

Comment: If `ls` fails, `cd -` is not executed.

Comment: Perhaps adding `... || cd - ` to mitigate.

Comment: So I have to back to the parent directory first anyway.